# Bejeweled Blitz "Perfect Game"

Tags: bejeweled-blitz

I have been playing Bejewled Blitz for quite some time now and I have begun to notice a peculiar pattern:

Normally I get a lot of terrible games with low scores simply in the 30,000's. As I keep playing, eventually, I get a really super lucky game where everything seems to work out perfectly (not sure what to call it, so I dub it a "Perfect Game"), and a high score is made.

These perfect games have another quality to them - everything seems to blow up by itself. Cascade after cascade keeps exploding everywhere (even when an x1,000 speed modifier has not been achieved yet), and as it runs out of speed, you simply supply it a match and watch it take off explode a lot of matches by itself some more. It feels as if the AI is "cheating" supplies itself with lots of cascading matches on purpose, and then matches those matches in pretty explosions.

I would like to know some more about these "Perfect Games". Is obtaining them a matter of simple probability? Does the game internally decide when you are loosing interest and throw you a "Perfect Game" as a bone? What else do you know about them? Am I just crazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no AI cheating itself in those games kind, it's just a matter of luck.

Also you could get a perfect board with a move that could trow a quadrillion of point ... and move the wrong gem.

Those game a too "dumb" to enhance that king of complex AI behavior.

Comment: I think you need to be a player of bejeweled blitz before you can talk about AI cheating and luck. In a normal play, the chances of getting a single cascading match that creates an explosive gem is quite rare. In these "perfect games" you get tens, twenties, thirty all in a row. The odds are too high for this to happen purely by probability.

Comment: I'm a player of bejewelled blitz, I played more than 700 games according to my stats. The odd may be high, but when you play a lot of game, the improbable has to happen, that the law of statistics.

Comment: Trivial aside regarding quadrillions of points: There is a maximum amount of points you can earn in Bejewled Blitz - I've only ever seen it attained with YouTube "cheat" videos (all the gems are power-up jewels). Once reached, the points don't go up anymore.

Comment: The quadrillions of points was an intentional exaggeration.

Comment: To be honest I find it completely reasonable that the game would intentionally give you large streaks every so often. It keeps players from getting annoyed at never doing well and since the new gems are chosen on the fly, it could easily do this without breaking its own rules. However I don't know for sure so I'm not leaving an answer.

Comment: The board is reasonably large; I'd be interested to know the statistical likelihood of a match appearing naturally on any random board. But in addition, removing a large number of gems at once increases the odds that new pieces will create a match. Finally, if there are NO good swaps on the board, the new pieces at the top will (almost) always produce a good swap and/or a natural match. Combine all this, and sometimes you just get a perfectly lucky streak.